# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError due to Native library issue?

Tags: java, classloader, flink-streaming

I am trying to use timezone finding service (https://github.com/dustin-johnson/timezonemap) in my Flink java job.
It worked fine in local machine and it worked fine initially in Flink server, but after 2-3 restart of the job it started giving NoClassDefFoundError error-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdInputStream
    at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.zstandard.ZstdCompressorInputStream.<init>(ZstdCompressorInputStream.java:43)
    at us.dustinj.timezonemap.data.DataLocator.getDataInputStream(DataLocator.java:22)
    at us.dustinj.timezonemap.TimeZoneMap.forRegion(TimeZoneMap.java:92)
    at us.dustinj.timezonemap.TimeZoneMap.forEverywhere(TimeZoneMap.java:60)
    at dtap.service.TimezoneService.<init>(TimezoneService.java:17)
    at functions.processors.KernelIntgrationProcessor.processElement(KernelIntgrationProcessor.java:47)
    at functions.processors.KernelIntgrationProcessor.processElement(KernelIntgrationProcessor.java:23)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator.processElement(ProcessOperator.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:704)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I looked at the code of ZstdCompressorInputStream class, it is loading native libraries.
And I found from below page that native library unloading issue could be the reason for this.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/rtrb_classload_viewer.html

Does anyone has faced similar issue or has idea to solve this problem?

Thanks
Mahendra

Comment: Check how many java services are running in the server, maybe you have more than one java server and you need to kill the process and restart the server without any other java services

Comment: hello have you solved this problem?